# How do I create an update function in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the question's cryptic to you then imagine how it is to me.  I'm not even sure *what* to look up to begin with.

Anyway, I'm making a to-do list and have just about everything else done, but I'm supposed to:

1. Update the click code of adding the item to the list, not only should it add the text, it should also add a textarea and a button. (Figured *this* out myself.)
2. Give this textarea and button a CLASS. (*Easy*.)
3. Once you have appended the textarea and button, along with the to-do text to the list, you can now give the button a click handler. (Wait, doesn't it already have one?)
4. This click handler will get the value of the textarea (from step 1) and then replace it with the existing item.  (What?)

Yes, it's help with homework; please don't throw rotten produce at me.  Collaboration's allowed, as is pasting code so long as it isn't done *blindly* (i.e., I pull something from the web and have to ask why it still doesn't work).

Moving on, I asked the teacher *what* existing item he meant:

> We have a button that creates list items, each of which has a button that lets you delete it.  But I don't know about any "update" buttons; and why would need an extra function to replace text when each list item is already an updatable text box?

To which he said:

> The reason for the extra update function is because the data in the text box does not exist in JavaScript, only in that text box, by making the update button pull the text from the text box we now have that text in JavaScript. While our simple app does not save any data, it's best practice to have data flowing from and to JavaScript, even though our app doesn't "need" it. The HTML and CSS is really only a simple interface that visitors can interact with, but JavaScript is how data is handled in the front-end.

I know the answer is just a few simple lines of code that I'll feel real dumb for not having figured out myself, but I don't want to spend hours on something so small because "suffering builds character."  What can I do to make the program work as instructed?  And how can I get better at figuring it out myself quickly?

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>To-Do List Front-End App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A to-do list app.">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
  /*vvvvvvvv CSS GOES BELOW THIS COMMENT vvvvvvvv*/

    #list-header {
        background-color: #e6e6fa;
    }

    #list-content {
        background-color: #bf94e4;
    }

  /*^^^^^^^^ CSS GOES ABOVE THIS COMMENT ^^^^^^^^*/
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- vvvvvvvv HTML GOES BELOW THIS COMMENT vvvvvvvv -->

  <div id="list-header">
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  </div>


  <div id="list-content">

    <form>
      <p>New Note: </p>
      <textarea id="new-note"></textarea>
    </form>

    <button id="submit-note">Create To-Do Item</button>

    <ul id="list">
    </ul>

  </div>

  <!-- ^^^^^^^^ HTML GOES ABOVE THIS COMMENT ^^^^^^^^ -->

  <script>
    /*global $*/
    /*vvvvvvvv JAVASCRIPT GOES BELOW THIS COMMENT vvvvvvvv*/

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#new-note").keypress(function (event) {   

        if (event.which == 13) { // Enters new list item when you press Return/Enter
            event.preventDefault();
            var noteText = $("#new-note").val();
            $("#list").append("<li>" + "<textarea class='notes'>" + noteText + "</textarea>" + " <button class='remove'>Delete</button></li>");

            $(".remove").click(function () { // Removes list item when you press the Delete button.
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });

            $("#new-note").val(""); // Blanks the text area when you enter an item.
        } // <- An IF statement, not a function

      });

      $("#submit-note").click(function () { // Enters a new list item when you click Create To-Do Item back in the HTML.
         var noteText = $("#new-note").val(); 
         $("#list").append("<li>" + "<textarea class='notes'>" + noteText + "</textarea>" + " <button class='remove'>Delete</button></li>");

         $(".remove").click(function () {  
           $(this).parent().remove();
         });

         $("#new-note").val(""); 

      });

    });

    /*^^^^^^^^ JAVASCRIPT GOES ABOVE THIS COMMENT ^^^^^^^^*/

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it a JavaScript course?  Is jQuery explicitly included? The reason I am asking is that if you're trying to learn JavaScript, don't use jQuery (until you know JavaScript **really** well).

Comment: I did not learn JS at school... But to do things *«even though our app doesn't "need" it»* sounds stupid to me. So if I were you, I would add the update button and get the actual value... I guess that is all to be done.

Comment: @user2182349, I'd love to ease into JavaScript first but the class is both supposed to be fast-paced and intensive **and** for complete beginners.  I'm being forced into jQuery, and having to make the best with what I have.

Comment: The risk is that if you only know jQuery and you end up in an environment where it isn't available, you'll be at a significant disadvantage.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agreed with @user2182349. Fast paced or not, to start with jQuery without knowing anything about the underlying language (JS) is completely backwards. You'll do yourself a favour if you add to your own homework and learn how to also do it in javascript.

Comment: @james.brndwgn at this point I'm pretty sure I'd learn more by building applications along YouTube tutorials and looking up new terms, along with any freebies I get from the library.  As for homework, have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you learn a lot on your own? Absolutely.  However, it is easy to learn only what you need to know to solve your immediate problem and you will miss out on learning alternatives.  I recommend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_First_(book_series).  Get one.  Do the whole book, from cover to cover.  Do everything.  You will be glad you did.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette I don't know how alerting works, so I'm commenting here to let you two know about an update.  I also can't seem to alert two people at once...

Comment: @james.brndwgn See above.

Comment: Only one text area and one update button can be added or multiple text areas and multiple update buttons needed ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

*Based on clearer requirements in comment.*

1. Your#1 - Add a text area, and add an update button;
2. Your#2 - attach click handler to update button;
3. Your#3 - this handler will take the value of the text area created in step
   1);
4. Extra step - **Let the user modity the text.**
5. Your#4 - use this value and replace the existing list item text;
6. Your#5 - the update should empty out text area.

Here is the code you need.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#new-note").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var noteText = $("#new-note").val();
      var listItem = "<li>" + noteText + " <button class='remove'>Delete</button><button class='update'>Update</button></li>";
      $("#list").append(listItem);
      $("#new-note").val("");
    }
  });

  $("#submit-note").click(function () {

    var noteText = $("#new-note").val();
    var listItem = "<li>" + noteText + " <button class='remove'>Delete</button><button class='update'>Update</button></li>";  // Your #1
    $("#list").append(listItem);
    $("#new-note").val("");
  });

  //
  // Button handlers using delegation (since those are dynamically created)
  //

  // REMOVE
  $("#list").on("click",".remove",function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  // UPDATE
  $("#list").on("click",".update",function () {  // Your #2
    var thisListItem = $(this).parent();
    thisListItem.find("button").remove();
    var thisListText = thisListItem.text().trim();  // Your #3
    var newTextarea = $("<textarea>").text(thisListText);
    thisListItem.empty().append(newTextarea).append(" <button class='updateOk'>Ok</button>");  // Needs two append. One for the jquery object and one for a string
  });

  // UPDATE OK
  $("#list").on("click",".updateOk",function () {
    var thisListItem = $(this).parent();
    var thetextareaVal = thisListItem.find("textarea").val();
    thisListItem.empty().append(thetextareaVal + " <button class='remove'>Delete</button><button class='update'>Update</button>"); // Your #4
  });



}); // END ready
```

In the code above, you'll find "Your #n" 1 to 4. The #5 is achieved by [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) two places, before and after user action.

The "extra step" occurs between the two update handlers... Because that needs an extra "ok" button... That's why it's 2 handlers.

That is all about event handlers...
You are dealing with dynamically created buttons, so again... Make sure to do at least the minimal reading about [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

**Delegation in short (and in my words):** Normally, the code will only apply only on existing elements (in the DOM) when the script is parsed. The only way around for this big problem is delegation.... That is about to attach the handlers needed for **future element** on a STATIC parent... The result is this static element WILL "distribute" the event on its matching child, if it has any when the event occurs.

To define an event handler within another **is a bad practice**. Please stop that now and forever. If you continue to do so anyway because it works... You will sooner or later encounter some strange behaviors sometimes hard to narrow down. [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=event+fire+twice+jquery)

And never loop over a handler definition. Loop over the HTML markup to add and give it classes already defined once. -- One class, one handler. Many events on a class can be one handler.

Beyond that, it only about to get/set values and replace/overwite/create elements.

A working demo is avalable here: [Your JsFiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/0mvo3f9L/).

Comment: Well, it works.  Thank you.  : )

Whether it's what the teacher wanted, however, is open to question.  We won't be getting to JSON for a couple of weeks.

Comment: Sadly it wasn't.  Here are the updated instructions: 1) Add a text area, and add an update button; 2) attach click handler to update button; 3) this handler will take the value of the text area created in step 1); 4) use this value and replace the existing list item text; 5) the update should empty out text area.

Comment: He also wanted us to _add_ to the initial class code (different from what I posted).  Here it is: jsfiddle.net/43oh08rj

Comment: Since that is an assignement... Feel free to ask about things I did not cover in my edit. ;)

Comment: I tried to check with the teacher if this code was what he wanted.  However, he answered my short and direct question with a long-winded complaint about the very class he was teaching.  I turned it in anyway.

Comment: As for not defining an event handler within another, I was only doing what was taught of me since I had no way of knowing better.  After looking at your code, however, I'll gladly use better practice.

Comment: Well... I think a *«long-winded complaint»* doesn't help a lot. I fixed an issue in the code by the way. It was inserted when I "cleaned" the code. lol I also fixed the Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your teacher simply wants you to grab the value of the textarea by clicking a button, you would do something like this in javascript. I'll leave you up to thinking of how to do it with jQuery.

The html

```
<textarea id="textarea">Blah blah blah</textarea>
<button id="btn">Get textarea</button>
```

The JS

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(textarea.value);
})

// The better way to do it as requiring the user to click a button is just....rediculous
// but perhaps you haven't learned about events yet.
textarea.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrndwgn/f9zb5rm7/4/

Comment: This one I'm still lost on.  We technically covered events, but the class lectures are blink-and-you'll-miss-it, consist almost entirely of copying along with the teacher's code, and the study materials are "here are some free online courses at the library, go look the rest up yourself."  The class is 16 weeks of material cut and crammed into 10, yet billed as being from beginner-to-budding career.  At least it's cheaper than free.

Comment: @AlgaeNymph Sorry to hear the course isn't as advertised. Sadly this is quite common these days with web development growing so quickly; every man and his dog is offering code schools. Might be worth checking out some reputable online platforms. They'll let you go at your own pace and I've heard decent things about them (I haven't used any of them myself though). Here's a couple off the top of my head https://www.codecademy.com/ or https://teamtreehouse.com/

Comment: @AlgaeNymph as for your current situation. What exactly is it that you need for your assignment? Perhaps you can provide a https://jsfiddle.net/ of what you have and describe where you need it to be. Happy to help you out.

Comment: You'll notice that the code's different from what I posted, which is because he wanted us to _add_ to it.  When he _finally_ looked at my front end and saw I was on the wrong track (even if he had all weekend to check the link I sent him!) he gave me updated instructions.  1) *Add* a text area, and add an update button; 2) attach click handler to update button; 3) this handler will take the value of the text area created in step 1); 4) use this value and replace the existing list item text; 5) the update should empty out text area.